# Display Noaa Elevation Data

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, netcdf4

I have found the example and would like to copy it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset

data = Dataset("Path/ETOPO1_Bed_g_gmt4.grd",'r')
print(data.variables.keys())

lon_range = data.variables['x_range'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y_range'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z_range'][:]
spacing = data.variables['spacing'][:]
dimension = data.variables['dimension'][:]
z = data.variables['z'][:]
lon_num = dimension[0]
lat_num = dimension[1]

lon = np.linspace(lon_range[0],lon_range[1],dimension[0])
lat = np.linspace(lat_range[0],lat_range[1],dimension[1])

topo = np.reshape(z, (lat_num, lon_num))


plt.imshow(topo, vmax=0)
```

However, I don't know where `x_range` comes from because when I print:

```
    print(data.variables.keys())
dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

How can I get around this problem?

the source: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/23904/etopo1-region-selection-in-python/23924#23924

Answer (score 0):

can you use [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/) for this? it seems like a great use case :)

Without seeing your data it's hard to know for sure if this will work out of the box, but it should be something as simple as this:

```py
ds = xr.open_dataset("Path/ETOPO1_Bed_g_gmt4.grd", engine='netcdf4')
print(ds)
ds.z.plot(vmax=0)
```